# How can I permanently get rid of ticks from my small dog?

Tags: dogs, diseases, ticks

I have a small dog. She is infested with so many ticks. I have done everything to get rid of them. I even hand picked all the ticks by hands, which took hours, multiple times. But they come back after 3 to 4 days in the same numbers.

I took her to a vet, he said that an injection will help with that problem. But he said that there is possibility of small dogs dying due to that injection. So I cannot do that. He gave me a powder to mix in water and give him bath. But that did not help either.

I want some solution for that problem.

Comment: where do you live,it is important you give more information in your question to get the best possible answer.there are remedies that do have a long time effect against ticks and fleas,just ask your vet about it.https://www.petmd.com/dog/parasites/evr_dg_10_ways_to_stop_ticks_from_biting_your_dog

Comment: I am from Pakistan. My vet said the injection can kill her. I gave her bath with a powder diluted in water. I tried shampoos. But the situation dos not change. A home remedy can also help

Comment: In the US we have a thing called a "flea bomb" which is used inside your home. It takes about 8 hours, but it will rid the home environment of fleas which is going to make a flea bath much more effective. Do you have such a thing in Pakistan?

Comment: your problem seems to be not so much clearing ticks from your dog (the baths do that) but preventing them from biting again. That's an environmental problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different ways to get rid of ticks:

### Flea / tick collars

They smell bad and have to be replaced regularly (I think once a year for most products), but they are an inexpensive way to keep ticks away from your dog. Ask your vet or buy one online, but make sure it repels ticks as well as fleas.

### Garlic

Garlic repels ticks by its smell and has been used for centuries to keep dogs free of fleas and ticks. You can buy foot pallets with garlic extract or feed fresh garlic.

Be aware that it takes a few weeks before the garlic takes effect and that the effect will be lost if you bathe your dog with soap or a detergent shampoo.

> It’s best to finely chop or crush the garlic clove, then wait a few minutes to allow the chemical reaction to occur. Here are some guidelines for daily feeding.
>
> | Dog's body mass | Amount of garlic |
> | --- | --- |
> | 10 to 15 pounds | half a clove |
> | 20 to 40 pounds | 1 clove |
> | 45 to 70 pounds | 2 cloves |
> | 75+ pounds | 2 and a half cloves |

[(source)](https://www.dogsnaturallymagazine.com/garlic-friend-or-foe/)

Please note that garlic becomes harmful for dogs if they eat vast amounts of it (5 grams of whole garlic per kilogram of the dog’s body weight).

### Powders or sprays

There are several commercial powders or sprays available that can be put into the dog's fur.

[Diatomaceous earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomaceous_earth) is a non-toxic powder and consists of fossilized remains of diatoms, a type of hard-shelled protist (chrysophytes). While non-toxic to humans and animals, this powder is lethal to ticks and fleas. **Do not use diatomaceous earth for swimming pool filters on your dog**. It is extremely dangerous to humans and pets and can cause internal bleeding. **Always use food-grade diatomaceous earth**. Do not use if your dog has a wound or rash, because the powder can irritate the skin.

One body spray you can do on your own is [this](https://www.dogsnaturallymagazine.com/natural-solutions-tick-season/):

> Cut a lemon into quarters and put into a pint jar. Cover with boiling water and let steep overnight. Put the solution in a spray bottle and spray all over the dog, especially behind the ears, around the head, at the base of the tail and in the arm pits.

Since the active component of this spray is the oil contained in the peel, you can probably use lemon or orange peels instead.

Personally I don't like to put citrus on a dog because most dogs find the smell just as repellent as ticks do. Make sure your dog doesn't get any of the spray into his eyes, nose or mouth.

**Apple cider vinegar** is also recommended by several sites as tick repellent. Add some of it to your dog's bathing water or rub or spray diluted vinegar into his fur. You can also add a tablespoon of apple cider vinegar to the dog’s water bowl.

### Essential oils

Eucalyptus, peppermint, citrus, tea tree, citronella, lavender and cedarwood oils are all either repelling or killing ticks. You can rub a few drops of them onto the collar of the dog or into the fur (especially behind the ears, in the armpits and at the base of the tail, where the skin is soft and ticks love to bite).

You have to replace the oil regularly. If you rub it directly into the fur, dust and dirt might collect in these spots and you may need to bathe your dog.

### How to remove ticks

- Grab the tick by the head or mouth parts right where they enter the skin. Do not grasp the tick by the body. Make sure you don’t crush the tick, which can force harmful bacteria to leave the tick and enter your pet’s bloodstream.
- Without jerking, pull firmly and steadily directly outward. Do not twist the tick as you are pulling.
- Using methods such as applying petroleum jelly, a hot match, or alcohol will NOT cause the tick to ‘back out.’ In fact, these irritants may cause the tick to deposit more disease-carrying saliva in the wound.
- After removing the tick, place it in a jar of alcohol to kill it. Ticks are NOT killed by flushing them down the toilet.
- Clean the bite wound with a disinfectant. If you want to, apply a small amount of a triple antibiotic ointment.
- Wash your hands thoroughly.