# My dog is involved in scabies disease

Tags: dogs, health, diseases, parasites, fleas

My dog is always scabing on its skin. Little lice type insects are present on its hair. I use some insecticides, but it cannot effectively remedy this. Would you please tell me some other suggestion?

Comment: what ever you do do not use insecticides on your dogs fur.ask your vet what is the suggested treatment. giving medical advice is not something i am comfortable with.

Comment: Try some flea shampoo.

Comment: You could have a look at [this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/21878/12501). Most suggestions work for fleas and ticks. But you should ask a vet what exactly these insects are and how you can help your dog. If a dog has a skin condition for a long time or has insects again and again, their immune system is often weakened and a vet can help them get stronger again to resist the insects.

Comment: Could youplease provide a picture? Most of us are probably thinking fleas, but it could be something else as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see something on the fur of your dog, it is very unlikely scabies. Scabies are a tiny mite living in the skin of animals (including humans).

[Here is a link to help you identify the problem](http://www.petsandparasites.org/dog-owners/scabies/); on the right hand side of this page are links to different parasites that are common on pets.

Your dog might have lice. You can identify this by holding your hand on one spot on the back of your dog for 20-30 seconds; if your dog has lice, you will see it when you remove your hand (lice are attracted to the heat of your hand).

The reason I mention lice is because it is not on the list on the web page.

The lice that dogs can get are not the same as the ones humans get, and the lice that cats can get do not infect dogs or humans.

The common remedies against fleas are effective against lice too.

I hope this can point you in the right direction to solve your dog's problem.